How was the year spoken in late 1800s England?
Would it have been as we do today, for example, 1889 as Eighteen-Eighty-Nine, or something else, such as Eighteen Hundred Eighty Nine, or Eighteen Hundred and Eighty-Nine?
Also curious about years in the first two decades of the 1900s, and how years from both time periods would have been spoken in the US, but mainly looking for the late 1800s in England.
To clarify, I'm looking for how a singular year would have be spoken, not references to a decade.

In ordinary conversation, "eighteen eighty-nine". "Eighteen hundred and eighty-nine" would only be used in certain very formal contexts.

I see evidence that past centuries abbreviated year references to the "tens' place" as we do today, thus in the early 1900s "the 90s" would refer to the 1890s. One example might be Longfellow's poem about Paul Revere's ride, "On the eighteenth of April, in Seventy-Five." Of course for an 1860 publication date, Longfellow was closer to 1875 than 1775, but then I suppose I might today speak of "the 30s," meaning the 1930s, and will have to stop doing so in 6 years.

They had the "Gay Nineties" (1890s), but Wikipedia says that was coined in the 1920s. The OED has "nineties" for the decade first used in 1853, although they don't have entries for every decade.

@StuartF — In the OED 1853 attestation, that’s the 1790s that are referred to.

@AndyBonner in the Longfellow poem it's quite explicit that he's talking about the past: "Listen, my children, and you shall hear / Of the midnight ride of Paul Revere / On the eighteenth of April, in Seventy-Five / Hardly a man is now alive / Who remembers that famous day and year."

Are you specifically looking for spoken, or will written suffice? Some of the answers below are giving examples of written English, or spoken English as it is written in books.

I don't think anyone has answered about how years in the first decade are pronounced: is the pronunciation "nineteen oh-two" universal, and if so, how is it spelt out? It seemed to take a while for this to settle down in the current century, as far as I can tell, with both "twenty oh-two" and "two thousand and two" being common.

Pronunciation of years as four-digit numbers in Britain
Contemporaneous nineteenth-century snippets of dialogue in English publications indicate that four-digit versions of each year were commonly pronounced as "eighteen" plus the decade and digit year. For example, from "Better Late Than Never," in Punch or the London Charivari (January 1, 1887):

In 1816—date you fix— / Your Magazine projected—nix— / But here's in eighteen eighty-six, / Our Murray!

And from "The Queen'z and the Fonetik Jubilee—A Fabel," in The Phonetic Journal (April 30, 1887):

But I digrés. This yeoman's riks / wer raizd in eighteen eighty-six, / and eighty-seven wil surely see / good Queen Victoria's Jubilee; / whom all the world delights to praiz / and honor, wishing length ov dayz.

A Google Books search for "eighteen hundred and eighty-six" turns up several matches from the United States (though far fewer than for "eighteen eighty-six"), but none from Britain. It seems reasonable to conclude that "eighteen eighty-six" was the most common way of pronouncing the year 1886 in full.

Two-digit short forms for years in Britain and the U.S.
Google Books searches for various single-year events in the United States during the late nineteenth century show frequent use of the last two digits of the year as part of the descriptive term for the event. Examples include "the panic of '57." "the treaty of '68," "the election of '72," and "the blizzard of '88"
Similar usage is evident in some results for Great Britain. For example, from Charles Reade & Dion Boucicault, Foul Play (1869):

At this very crisis  came the panic of '66. Overend and Gurney broke; and Wardlaw's experience led him to fear that, sooner or later, there would be a run on every bank in London. Now he had borrowed £80,000 at one bank, and £35,000 at another: and, without his ships, could not possibly pay a quarter of the money.

From testimony from William Wreghitt in Report of the Commissioners Appointed to Inquire into the Existence of Corrupt Practices at the Last Election and at Previous Elections of Members to Sit in Parliament for the Borough of Beverly (1870):

I think we were upon the close of the election of '68 when we left off?—Yes.
There was, as I understand, a sharp contest in '67? —Yes, there was; I was a candidate on that occasion.
...
And I believe you did not vote in '68?—No.
That shows me I am dealing with a very clever man. I say it advisedly. I suppose I may ask you, Mr, Wreghitt, you made yourself acquainted with the Bribery Act of '67?—Of '68; July '68.

And from John O'Rourke, The History of the Great Irish Famine of 1847: With Notices of Earlier Irish Famines (1875):

Thus was the cultivation of the potato extended in various ways, until it had become the principal food of nineteen-twentieths of the population long before the Famine of '47.


Short forms for decades in Britain and the U.S.
With regard to decade names, it appears from Google Books search results that referring to decades by their tens number ("the sixties," "the seventies," "the eighties," "the nineties") was fairly well established in both Britain and North America by the year 1900. One early instance appears in "Will It All Be the Same One Hundred Years Hence?" (dated November 1869) in The Powder Magazine (London, January 1870):

The "sixties" will be gone before / This Magazine is read; / Before the "sixties" come again— / Why! we shall all be dead.
The future generations, when / A hundred years are o'er, / Shall letters with a "sixty" date, / But we shall never more.

Similarly, Richard Jenkins (identified as "A Planter") titled his book of reminiscences about his life in Ceylon, Ceylon in the Fifties and the Eighties: a Retrospect and Contrast of the Vicissitudes of the Planting Enterprise During a Period of Thirty Years, and of Life and Work in Ceylon (Colombo, 1886):

I must endeavour to get along from the "fifties" to the "eighties" with as few personal allusions as possible , though I know of no better way than to follow the lead of my own movements during that interval of time, insofar as it came under my own observation. I have lived for years in each of the Uva districts—Haputale, Badulla, Udapussellawa and Madulsima—and know all the roads and paths, rivers and fords, hills and valleys in them all, except such bridges and roads as have been made in recent years; and by the same token, this last statement reminds me that I know nothing of Uva in the "eighties."

From an item about the Edinburgh Association for the Promotion of Reform in Medical Education in The Lancet (London, January 16, 1892) has this:

This increase [in number of students, from 678 in 1870–71 to 1,603 in 1880–81] is accounted for by the influence of distinguished teachers in the school, by the fact that in England the only entrance to the profession for the average student was by a college diploma, and by the Edinburgh school being distinguished for the excellence of the practical instruction given in it, and that in this last respect it was not surpassed by anything then obtainable in England. During the eighties the number of students continued to rise, and reached in 1889-90 to 2003. During the eighties no corresponding increase to the teaching power or adequate improvement in the medical curriculum of the University was made , notwithstanding the fact that, owing to public support,the medical school of the University had been accommodated in a building which it was anticipated would fulfil all modern requirements.

And from a letter from Godfrey Burchett of Farthingstone Rectory, dated January 23, 1896, to the editor of The Author (London, April 1, 1896):

One does not express nature by presenting as natural events series after series of ingeniously interwoven circumstances carrying certain lives to certain situations useful to the novelist, and happening ad hoc ; nor does one express nature by depicting as human lives trade characters bowdlerized or broadened to the taste of the fifties or the sixties, or the eighties or the nineties, of this or any other century.


Here’s the source for the OED’s 1853 attestation for nineties.

Any examples of the four digit year (first section) which aren't poetry?  My concern would be that an alternate form might be chosen in order to fit a particular meter, which would be understandable but not necessarily particularly common in prose or dialog.

@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: A Google Books search for "eighteen seventy" for the period 1849–1896, yields various relevant matches, such as this one from Great Thoughts from Master Minds, a London periodical (1891): "He does not bring back Eighteen-seventy into Eighteen-seventy-one, and say, 'There, I have brushed it up for you, and made the best of it I can; you must try it again.'"

Any research on the format "one thousand eight hundred [and] eighty six"?

@shoover: A Google Books search across the period 1849–1896 yields one unique match for "one thousand eight hundred eighty-six"—from a collection of documents from the Maine Legislature: "... during the year one thousand eight hundred eighty-five, and three hundred dollars during the year one thousand eight hundred eighty-six." The unique matches for "one thousand eight hundred and eighty-six" amount to several dozen, but many involve dollar amounts, not years, and all appear in government laws, records, and  other official documents. ...

...The London Gazette of September 27, 1887, for example, offers this instance: ...

... "And whereas by Orders in council of the twenty-ninth day of June, one thousand eight hundred and eighty-two, and the tenth day of November, one thousand eight hundred and eighty-six, Her Majesty was pleased to rescind the said conditions and regulations (except in so far as the same related to Certificates of Competency granted to Masters, Mates, or Engineers by the Governor of Hong Kong), and to substitute therefor the conditions and regulations set out in the schedule to the said last recited Order in Council, and numbered 1 to 10 respectively, ...

... and to declare that the same should apply to all Colonial Certificates granted under any of the said recited orders:" I didn't find any matches where people writing outside formal legalistic settings used either of these long forms for four-digit years.

Four-digit years were very common before 1800. IDK if it's the pace of change, or the disbelief that it will go to 20xx, or hurry, or just plain hubris that led to the first two digits so being increasingly dropped in the 19th and particularly the 20th century.

In formal legal documents the traditional format was "in the year of our Lord one thousand eight hundred and sixty-two" in both the US and UK. This also appears in other written contexts, for example Dickens uses it. Of course "year of our Lord" is just Anno Domini (AD) translated into English.

@SvenYargs https://www.dickens-online.info/a-tale-of-two-cities.html para 3. Perhaps Dickens was deliberately using an artificially formal phrase here for effect?

@MichaelKay That format, of course, has even made its way into slightly more surprising places (albeit with hundred left out for scansion purposes).

Do you have any sources for first-decade years, such as 1902?

@MichaelKay: I haven't looked for searched the (multiple) forms of the first decade of a century. I do remember being struck by the way my grandfather (who who was from far western Kentucky) pronounced his birth year—"nineteen aught three"—because no one where I lived (southern Texas) used "aught" to mean "zero" except in connection with rifle cartridge sizes.
